# HTML relative linking not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

So I have an internal link that leads to another page in the website. However, when clicked and hovered, it appears to lead just back to the page it is on.

```
    a href scr ="../countries/list.html">here</a>
```

I am certain this is the correct path to the file (up a level and then down into that directory).

The actual link on the webpage leads to

```
    file:///C:/Users/alex.mckinley/Desktop/Kronos%20Import%20Guidlines/home/home.html
```

when it should lead to

```
    file:///C:/Users/alex.mckinley/Desktop/Kronos%20Import%20Guidlines/countries/list.html
```

Any thoughts?

I am using the most updated version of Firefox to test this in if that matters

Comment: dont set src, set href

Comment: a href scr ="../countries/list.html">here</a>  change to  <a href="../countries/list.html">here</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inserted the characters `scr` between the name (`href`) of the attribute and the rest  (`="some URL"`).

This renders your HTML invalid (use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), it will spot this type of issue for you) and is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you! i just completely missed that.